# sqlite2 does not work in 11.10

Tags: 11.10, php, sqlite

I have configured Ubuntu 11.10 in my PC. I have installed `php 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.8`.

My problem is that after PC upgrade, sqlite2 is not supported in PHP. Also `sqlite3` database is locked whenever I have executed any insert/update query in PHP.

Any idea about this? I want work on both database simultaneously.

Comment: I don't think this question belong here. You should post this in stackoverflow.com. Also check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61085/sqlite-php-read-only

Comment: @shantanu: It's about how to install a package supporting a feature, so seems on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by read the solution given on below link

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/875262